# Why my HttpSecurity doesn't apply configuration for admin path?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to create web application with user pages and admin pages. I want users see user pages without login through login form and access to admin section through login form. Admin section should be accessed via "/admin_panel" url path. I secured this url path with **configure(HttpSecurity http)** method, but nothing was happened - user pages and admin pages opens without form login.

**WebSecurityConfig.java:**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin_panel/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin().and()
        .httpBasic()
        ;   
}

@Autowired
 public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
      .usersByUsernameQuery("select name,password,enabled from users where name=?")
      .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username=?")
      .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
 } 
}
```

**WebController.java:**

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

@GetMapping(value= {"/"})
    public String index(){
        return "index";
}

@GetMapping(value= {"/admin_panel/admin"})
    public String admin(){
        return "admin";
    }
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Would you like that admin_panel to have no security?

Comment: @Cristiano Bombazar, admin_panel should have security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `@Configuration` annotation to WebSecurityConfig class will fix the problem.

Comment: Login form appeared now, but on all pages. I need to exclude user pages from logining.

Comment: Which is another question (and basically comes down to adding the security rules for that).

Comment: .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/page-for-user").permitAll()
in the configure method of WebSecurityConfig, but this is another question as @M.Deinum said.